# Unable to add new user claim due to constraint conflict of primary key

Tags: c#, oracle, constraints, addition

I have a net core web app net core 3.1 using Oracle database. The tables are generated using MS.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools ('add-migration' & 'update-database' commands).
The auto-generated tables specifically, AspNetUserClaims & AspNetRoleClaims both uses Oracle's auto identity generation.

The issue I have is with the given code, I am just not able to add a new user claim due to constraint conflict.

> OracleException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYSTEM.PK_AspNetUserClaims) violated.

SQL for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."AspNetUserClaims" 
(   
    "Id" NUMBER(10,0) GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UserId" NVARCHAR2(450) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ClaimType" NVARCHAR2(2000), 
    "ClaimValue" VARCHAR2(3000 CHAR), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_AspNetUserClaims" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
     ......
)
```

C# code:

```
IdentityUserClaim<string> userClaim = new IdentityUserClaim<string> { UserId = user.Id, ClaimType = "WT", ClaimValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonWebToken) };
//// var last = await _context.UserClaims.LastOrDefaultAsync(); // dumb workaround
//// userClaim.Id = last == null ? 1 : last.Id + 1;
await _context.UserClaims.AddAsync(userClaim);
```

1. GENERATED ALWAYS, attempting to insert a value will result in error, but id is an integer with value 0 as default.
2. GENERATED DEFAULT, generated if no value is provided, same as above, an integer is 0 as default.
3. GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL, integer is not nullable.

How can I proceed to create a user claim from here on?

Please ignore the mixed case, system schema, quotations or what not.

Comment: Not a cause of this issue but I've always found that using " around MiXeDcAsE column names in orracle causes the most horrendous headaches elsewhere. Use case insensitive column names every time

Comment: Try going back to Core2.0.  Everybody is having issues with Entity in Core 3.0 and 3.1.

Comment: @ CaiusJard & Littlefoot, point taken (though SQL code is merely copied out of SQL Developer, table's SQL tab). 
@ jdweng, you must be joking. Since MS.EFC.Tools is 2.2.6 , shouldn't it be somewhat core 2.0?

Comment: I don't know if "everybody" is a fair comment- we don't have any significant issues with our ef 3.x projects. We don't use aspnet membership stuff though.

Answer (score 0):

Generated by default, while providing its value manually:

```
SQL> create table test(id number generated by default as identity primary key, name varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Little');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Foot');
insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Foot')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (DP_4005.SYS_C001685565) violated
```

If you omit ID:

```
SQL> insert into test (name) values ('Foot');
insert into test (name) values ('Foot')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (DP_4005.SYS_C001685571) violated
```

---

Generated always; ID value provided manually:

```
SQL> create table test(id number generated always as identity primary key, name varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Little');
insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Little')
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column
```

So - don't provide the ID, let Oracle handle it:

```
SQL> insert into test (name) values ('Little');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (name) values ('Foot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID NAME
---------- ----------
         1 Little
         2 Foot
```

---

Conclusion? Let database handle columns which are to be generated; don't provide those values manually.

---

Apart from that, the first line you posted:

```
CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."AspNetUserClaims"
```

has 2 "errors" you'd want to avoid:

- SYSTEM, as well as SYS, are special users in an Oracle database, they own it and should **not** be used except by DBAs while maintaining the database. Creating your own objects in any of those schemas is/can be a HUGE mistake. If you do something wrong, you might destroy the database.
- double quotes (Caius Jardas already commented): don't use them in Oracle. You can use any letter case you want, but object names will default to uppercase.

See a few examples:

```
SQL> create table TesT (nAME varCHAr2(10));

Table created.

SQL> select table_name, column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'TEST';

TABLE_NAME           COLUMN_NAME
-------------------- --------------------
TEST                 NAME

SQL> select NamE from TEst;

no rows selected
```

But, with double quotes, you have to match letter case every time (and, of course, use double quotes every time):

```
SQL> create table "TesT" ("nAME" varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> select table_name, column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'TesT';

TABLE_NAME           COLUMN_NAME
-------------------- --------------------
TesT                 nAME

SQL> select * From test;
select * From test
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select name from "test";
select name from "test"
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select name from "TesT";
select name from "TesT"
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "NAME": invalid identifier


SQL> select "nAME" from "TesT";

no rows selected

SQL>
```

So - forget about double quotes while in Oracle.